# curl over HTTPS

Tags: website, wget, curl

I've just setup a website/webserver, and just got it verified by ZeroSSL, but when i try and run curl or wget over it, it errors. I could bypass this by running `wget --no-check-certificate` or `curl -k` but I'd rather have it work out of the box considering that a decent part of the website is built around installing files. Is there anyway to fix this without downloading certs or not checking them?

Curl error

`curl https://gitnet.me`

 `curl: (60) ssl certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Wget error

 `wget https://gitnet.me`

```
Resolving gitnet.me... 104.207.144.166
Connecting to gitnet.me|104.207.144.166|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify gitnet.me's certificate, issued by 'CN=ZeroSSL RSA Domain Secure Site CA,O=ZeroSSL,C=AT':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority
```

Comment: "Is there anyway to fix this without downloading certs or not checking them?" - You have to do one or the other there is no way around that. Why are you against installing the TLS certificate in the certificate store?

Comment: What did you try to resolve the issue? Did you try one various suggestions on the stackexchange sites that pop up when you feed a search engine of your choice with the error message?

Comment: @mashuptwice I've looked at multiple sites and all i can find is posts relating  to selff-signed certs, I do actually have a CA. (Zerossl as mentioned in the original post) Do i have to put the cert  in the root of the webserver maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your webserver [isn't correctly configured](https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058296114-Missing-Intermediate-Certificate) to serve the ZeroSSL intermediate certificate, so clients can't see whether your server certificate actually leads to a known root CA – there's a gap between the two.

("ZeroSSL Secure Site CA" itself is not a root CA – commercial root CAs don't directly issue HTTPS certificates, they always put an intermediate CA in between.)

Your site works with web browsers because they cache previously seen intermediates, precisely to deal with websites misconfigured like yours, but other HTTPS clients usually don't do that so the server has to provide all intermediate certs regardless.

If you're using ACME with Certbot, configure your webserver to use `fullchain.pem`, *not* cert.pem, as the SSL certificate. Other ACME clients have similar files.

If you're still downloading certificates by hand, [according to ZeroSSL's docs](https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060120113-Download-Certificate) you should've received a `ca_bundle.crt` file together with the certificate. You should combine the two files (they're just text files – append the ca_bundle below the issued certificate), then configure your webserver to use the combined file.

1. `cat certificate.crt ca_bundle.crt > cert_with_chain.crt`
2. `SSLCertificateFile /etc/.../cert_with_chain.crt`
3. *You really should use ACME though*

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but I used acme.sh, can i just alter my apache2.conf and set the fullchain.pem in the .acme.sh/ directory? [EDIT: Doing that fixed it]